# In WCF, how do you customize how a type is represented in WSDL?

Tags: wcf, serialization, wsdl

We are looking to publish parts of our business layer through WCF. Our API uses a CQRS architecture that already lines up nicely with having discrete POCO inputs and POCO outputs. We'd like to reuse these POCO classes rather than duplicate them all into contracts. For example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyDomain.SomeQuery.Result GetStuff(MyDomain.SomeQuery.Arguments args);
}
```

My problem is that we have some not-strictly-POCO structs in our POCOs.

```
class Arguments
{
    public StudentId Id { get; set; }
}
```

These identifier structs can be represented as a string. In our ASP.NET MVC project, we use type converters to serialize these properties to strings in outgoing JSON, and model bind from strings on incoming requests.

Ideally we'd like these identifiers to be represented as strings in the WSDL/MEX in WCF, serialized and deserialized using type converters. The client should be entirely unaware that we have this thing inside our domain.

The alternative is to make duplicates of all of these classes, which would add an element of risk and tediousness to the process.

Comment: Maybe you can do using XmlElement, like this:
[DataMember]
[XmlElement(DataType="string")]
Student Id....
If does not work, you can also write a custom serializer/deserializer

Comment: Thanks for the response! We wouldn't be able to modify our existing domain classes. I'll look at custom serializes, but when WCF generates a WSDL, we'd like our custom structures to look like a string, so the client isn't confused, and can just pass a string.

Comment: Part of the solution might be to use IWsdlExportExtension. If I implement this and attach it to the contract(s), I can manipulate the WSDL as it is generated, allowing the client to think my property is a string. I haven't quite got this manipulation of the WSDL to work yet, but I get the vibe it could be done. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Interesting, it can be a solution, but I was just wondering if can have any problem with serialize/deserialize, due to the change in the wsdl schema?

Comment: Yeah, that would be problem 2. :) I am not investing enough time into this problem yet to make much progress (a few minutes googling and experimenting in between other things) and hoping for a better answer. Deserializing though: our structs on the model can be assigned to from a string via operator overloads or type converters. Serializing... I'm not sure.